# How to cover the Js code inside the Jquery using chutzpah

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, chutzpah

Writing test case using chutzpah. Code inside the

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

is not running. How to cover the js code inside the Jquery ready function?

Comment: What codes are not running? A function?

Comment: yes there are few functions inside it

Comment: You can't call the functions initiated inside the `$(document).ready(function () {`. outside it.